# prepare and execute SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, psql

When I run the following

```
PREPARE fooplan (dataset text) AS
create or replace VIEW $dataset$_view as (
  select * from $dataset$ one where not exists(
     select* from $dataset$ two where
     ((one.x <= two.x and one.y <two.y) OR
     (one.x < two.x and one.y <=two.y))) ORDER BY y DESC, x DESC);
```

in psql and press enter, no error or success statement comes up. I think the terminal's expecting me to add something just not sure what? 
Can anyone see what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

You've created your prepared statement, you must execute then:

```
EXECUTE fooplan('foobar');
```

More info about it [here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)